# how to use settimeout for looping a function

Tags: jquery

i have a slideshow with 4 pictures which has a pagination, now i want them to be show one by one in a loop, for looping i have this code:

```
  function myfn(interaltime) {
  setTimeout('$("#picgallery_pagging li:eq(0)").trigger("click")', 0);
  setTimeout('$("#picgallery_pagging li:eq(1)").trigger("click")', interaltime);
  setTimeout('$("#picgallery_pagging li:eq(2)").trigger("click")', interaltime*2);
  setTimeout('$("#picgallery_pagging li:eq(3)").trigger("click")', interaltime*3);
  setTimeout('myfn('+interaltime+')',interaltime*4);
  };
  myfn(3000);
```

my problem: it doesn't work properly and just runs it once and interaltime variable is empty in the second round

each button in pagination runs my custom function effect for showing the pic and as u see i have to trigger click function on each button on my pagination.(i dont know how to use delay in jquery with my own function)

**note**: i checked intervaltime variable in console log and it was empty on the seconde turn! but i dont know how to fix it!
**edit**: i used setInterval but still intercaltime variable was empty in the second ture

Comment: try setInterval instead of setTimeout

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to be using setInterval if you're looping?

Comment: This won't work; the setTimeout won't let the code after it wait. It will just wait X amount of milliseconds to execute the inners of the functions. So they'll all happen simultaneously still.

Comment: Why would he use setInterval instead? it has the side effect of calling the methods many times at once if the current tab loses focus without gaining any benefits.

Comment: Your code works as-is. http://jsfiddle.net/A8BCb/

Comment: Do you have a typo in your actual code? In this question, you've spelled the variable 3 different ways already: interaltime, intervaltime, intercaltime.

Comment: I accidentally used `intervaltime` too in my fiddle at first. Gotta love miss-spelled variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing strings to `setTimeout` - this is not best practise, and can be downright unreliable.

Try this, instead:

```
function autoclick($el, delay) {
    var i = 0, n = $el.length;
    (function loop() {
        $el.eq(i).trigger('click');    // do your thang
        i = (i + 1) % n;               // increment and reset (if required)
        setTimeout(loop, delay);       // loop "recursively"
    })();                              // invoke immediately
}

autoclick($('#picgallery_pagging li'), 1000);
```

It eliminates the repetition in your code, and arranges to call itself over and over for each single element, not for the whole batch of four.

The call isn't *really* recursive, even though it may look like it, because it's actually the browser's event loop that's responsible for dispatching the function call over and over.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/PfmVt/

Comment: @PersianMan I've just updated the code slightly for efficiency.  It'll now also automatically iterate over however many entries you have in the gallery.

Comment: i checked that as well. your knowledge and speed in coding is amazing

Comment: @PersianMan thanks :)  I've now gone and updated it further, making the set of elements a parameter so there's no hard coded dependencies on your specific HTML layout within the function.

Comment: thank you again. i just changed var i = 0 to var i = -1. because it didnt load the first pic at beggining. i used the code in my site:http://pureislam.org/ . click on multimedia and see the rsult of your help

Comment: what if i use a class instead of "#picgallery_pagging". it is ok if i use only one pagination. if i use two pagination with one class it dose not work

Comment: @PersianMan you'll need to call the function once for each _group_ of elements that you want to click.  If you try to combine them in one call it'll treat every matching element as a single set.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be like this:

```
function myfn(interaltime) {
    function wrapper(){
        do_stuff();
        setTimeout(wrapper, interaltime);
    }
    setTimeout(wrapper, 0);
}
```

You are basically setting the timeout to run the same function again and again. This is quite simplified sample, not even trying to provide means for cancelling the loop. Also, please note that it's not a recursive call in any way, so you won't run into a stackoverflow issues.

even simpler option is to use setInterval:

```
function myfn(interaltime) {
    return setInterval(do_stuff, intervaltime);
}
```

This way you will be able to cancel the loop, something like

```
var loop = myfn(100);
//somewhere later
clearInterval(loop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
                $("#picgallery_pagging li:eq(0)").trigger("click");
             }, 0);
```

instead of

```
  setTimeout('$("#picgallery_pagging li:eq(0)").trigger("click")', 0);
```

And repeat for all of your other setTimeouts.  Essentially, use an anonymous function for the setTimeout